# Prove that this statement about A and B is true.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$,
If $AB - BA = A^2$
Prove that $ (B - A)^{2014} = B^{2013}(B-2014A)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will prove $(B-A)^n = B^{n-1}(B - nA)$ by induction:

Firstly, when $n = 1$, obviously it's true.

Suppose it's true for $n=k$, then 
$$(B-A)^{k+1} = (B-A)^{k}(B-A) = B^{k-1}(B- kA)(B-A) = B^{k-1}(B^2 - BA - kAB + kA^2)$$

plug in $A^2 = AB - BA$, we get
\begin{align}
(B-A)^{k+1} &= B^{k-1}(B^2 - BA -kAB +k(AB - BA)) \\
&= B^{k-1}(B^2 - (k+1)BA) = B^k(B - (k+1)A)
\end{align}

Now it's done.